# Corresponding values in one column based on values in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df below . I need to build a function so that based on values in column 1(that is d) I need to have corresponding values in column d5

```
       s1
       d  d1  d2         d5
  1  A&B  A    B    factor&integer
  2  A&C  A    C    factor&factor
  3  A&D  A    D    factor&integer
  4  A&E  A    E    factor&factor
```

So basically i need to build a function called 'class1'. So for class1(A&E) the output should be factor&factor and for class1(A&D) the output should be factor&integer. Hope you got my point . I tried myself with the below code but still getting error.

```
 yt<-list()    
 class1 <- function(name1,variable)
 {
 for(variable in s1$d)
 {
 yt[variable] <- name1[which(name1$d==variable),4]
 yt[variable] <- print(as.data.frame(yt))
 }
 }
```

Now if I type class1(s1,A&C). I should get factor&factor. But I am not getting this

Comment: is column 5 not from column 3 and 4? `paste(d3,d4,sep="&")`?

Comment: Yes it is. Why?

Comment: But I need corresponding values between d and d5

Comment: what do you mean by corresponding values?

Comment: For example, for A&E in column d, i need to have corresponding value in column d5 that is factor&factor. Basically i need to write a function

Comment: But you can read it directly from column d3 and d4 and paste is as proposed by @Onyambu no?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please review it

Comment: do you have columns 3 and 4? ie d3 and d4? if not, how do you know when it is factor and when it is integer?

Comment: please ignore columns d3 and d4. I have edited

Comment: your question is incomplete.

Comment: Is it not clear?

Comment: i need to build a function called 'class1'. So for class1(A&E) the output should be factor&factor and for class1(A&D) the output should be factor&integer. Hope you got my point

Comment: I tried the solution myself, Please review the edited question. But I am missing something hence getting error. Could you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get a function to match a variable similar to column `d` to column `d5`, then try this one

```r
s1 <- data.frame(
  d = c("A&B","A&C","A&D","A&E"),
  d1 = c("A","A","A","A"),
  d2 = c("B","C","D","E"),
  d5 = c("factor&integer", "factor&factor", "factor&integer", "factor&factor"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

class1 <- function(data,var) {
  data[which(data$d==var),"d5"]
}
class1(s1, "A&C")
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i wanted. I tried my best to convey the message :) I need it as a function. My post has a example as well

Comment: Hi Thomas. I tried to build a function but still getting error. I have edited my question here

Comment: Ok your question wasn't quite clear, sorry for my misunderstanding. You didn't want to match column `d` to `d5` automatically for larger scale, you only wanted to have a funciton based on your `s1`, correct?

Comment: Perfect and you made it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Beneath the vote buttons you can find a small green tick. You can click that in case somebody answered your question correctly. Welcome to stackoverflow though!